# How to statistically validate that one clustering technique is more effective than other on Binary data

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering, jaccard-similarity

**Problem statement -** Idea is to cluster students based on their assessment pattern and score.

**Data** =  I have a data set that contains Binary data of students answers(Correct/incorrect) which i have recoded as 1 & 0.
Its a 10*100 matrix of 10 students answering 100 questions. Looks like this

[image]

I have tried distance calculation formula of following 2 techniques

Let be the contingency table of binary data such as n11 = a, n10 = b, n01 = c and n00 = d. All these distances are of type d = sqrt(1 - s) with s a similarity coefficient.

1. [Sokal & Michener](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_20.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_proximities_measures_binary_data.htm) 
   formula= (a+d) / (a+b+c+d)
2. Jaccard Index
   formula =  a / (a+b+c)

I have found that "Sokal & Michener" works best for me just by looking at the clusters it found and i already knew the pattern in the data very well(*i created dummy data*) and hence i came to this conclusion of choosing "Sokal & Michener"

But is there a way to statistically verify that 1 algorithm works better then another?

Also can you suggest any other clustering technique for this problem statement?

Thanks

Comment: How do you define "works better"?

Comment: Intuitively i would like students clustered together who have similar pattern of answering and similar scores. Hence i went with Sokal & Michener as it works using intersection and union

Comment: Jaccard is a widely accepted measure of "similarity", and it also works using intersection and union, doesn't it? So how do you define "better similarity"?

Comment: Yes it does but jaccard only uses 11 and doesn't consider 00. In my case even 00 is a pattern that should be considered.